# How to search and output with a form input value using PDO

Tags: php, mysql, pdo

I am trying to perform a search action by getting a value from HTML form using PDO and display the results in the same page. I am getting no errors also no results. Please advise! i am beginner.

```
<?php 
require_once 'db_alternate2.php';
session_start(); 

if (isset($_POST['submit'])) {
try {
$conn = new PDO("mysql:host=$host;dbname=$dbname", $username, $password);

$payrl_search = trim($_POST['empname_search']);

$sql = "SELECT * FROM payroll_db 
WHERE 'pay_staff_name' 
LIKE '$%payrl_search%'"; 

$q = $conn->query($sql);
$q->setFetchMode(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);

} catch (PDOException $pe) {
die("Could not connect to the database $dbname :" . $pe->getMessage());
}
}
```

my php code inside html is

```
         <table>
         <tbody>
         <?php while ($r = $q->fetch()): ?>
             <tr>
             <td><?php echo htmlspecialchars($r['pay_emp_id'])?></td>
             <td><?php echo htmlspecialchars($r['pay_staff_name']); ?></td>
             <td><?php echo htmlspecialchars($r['pay_month_sal']); ?></td>
             <td><?php echo htmlspecialchars($r['pay_amount']); ?></td>
             <td><?php echo htmlspecialchars($r['pay_bankname']); ?></td>
             </tr>
         <?php endwhile; ?>
         </tbody>
         </table>
```

I am getting these errors:

> 1. **Undefined variable: q**
> 2. **Fatal error: Call to a member function fetch() on a non-object**

i think my error part is

```
         <?php while ($r = $q->fetch()): ?>
```

Comment: The error simply means your query didn't work and is returning a null/false value and false is not an object so check very well and make sure your query evaluates to true

Comment: @danidee:_Thanks!_I have double checked my db links and names, everything looks perfect. Although i did a mistake, which i found now `LIKE '$%payrl_search%'` which i've as `LIKE '%$payrl_search%'` . but still the problem remains. Please advise if i can rewrite my query in any other way!

Comment: remove the quotes for `WHERE 'pay_staff_name'` that's a column. also `'$%payrl_search%'` the `$` is in the wrong spot

Comment: @Fred-ii- I tried without quotes and corrected the `$` also.. didn't work

Comment: is your form using POST and that your element holds the name attribute with no typos lettercase etc? same for your submit button

Comment: @Fred-ii- `<form action="payroll_result.php" method="post">` is my form tag

Comment: what about your input, is it named? i.e. `name="empname_search"`

Comment: @Fred-ii- yes!! i have the same name `<input type="text" name="empname_search" placeholder="Employee Name"/>`

Comment: Try changing `$q->setFetchMode(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);` to `$results = $q->setFetchMode(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);` and removing `trim` from your POST array while making sure you have something in your table that matches the query. Other than that, I don't know what else could be causing this. Do a `var_dump();` to see what's going through and add error reporting to see if it catches anything else.

Comment: I tested your code and was successful with the fixes that were outlined above. Make sure you've chosen the right database and table and that your columns also all exist, while checking for the column types. Plus, what's in here `require_once 'db_alternate2.php';`? Add error reporting to the top of your file(s) right after your opening PHP tag 
for example `<?php error_reporting(E_ALL); ini_set('display_errors', 1);` then the rest of your code, to see if it yields anything.

Comment: I'm guessing your connection variables may have something to do with this. Make sure you've chosen the right db etc. - am moving on, good luck.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Reference - What does this error mean in PHP?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12769982/reference-what-does-this-error-mean-in-php)